# The position of a particle after time 't' is $(t-4)^3 (3-2t)^2$ metres. Find the velocity, acceleration and jerk of the particle?

Tags: calculus

To find the velocity - f'(x)
Acceleration - f''(x)
Jerk - f'''(x).

I differentiated it but I get answers different from the book I'm using. Could you work it out for me.

Comment: What answers did you get? Often, people can guess what went wrong from that information.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see the function in the title, $f(t)=(t-4)^3(3-2t)^2$, so $$f'(t)=[3\times(t-4)^{3-\color{blue}{1}}]\times(3-2t)^2+(t-4)^3\times[2\times(-2)\times(3-2t)^{2-\color{blue}{1}}]\\=1035t^2-240t^3+20t^4-1880t+1200$$ I think $f''(t)$ is now easy to find.

Comment: @amWhy: Hello Amy. Nice to see you again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

HINT :

You can use the following :

$$\{f(t)g(t)\}^\prime=f^\prime (t) g(t)+f(t)g^\prime (t).$$

Letting
$$f(t)=(t-4)^3,g(t)=(3-2t)^2,$$
we have
$$f^\prime(t)=3(t-4)^{3-1}(t-4)^\prime=3(t-4)^2,$$
$$g^\prime(t)=2(3-2t)^{2-1}(3-2t)^\prime=2(3-2t)\cdot (-2)=-4(3-2t).$$